# C# Method that loops list and access different Properties at different times

Tags: c#, list, for-loop

So I have a `List<Product>` that I need to loop and calculate some stuff. Every `Product` has propery `Price` and `Tax`. What I want to do is to have a method where I can loop throught the list and calculate the total price and the total tax, but I don't want to write to methods for this.

At the moment I have this:

```
private double calculateTotalPrice()
        {
            List<Product> temp = this.GetList();
            double price = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
            {
                price += temp[i].Price;
            }

            return price;
        }
```

But with this method I need to have one method for calculating Price and another for Tax. Is it possible to change this method so that I can call it and at one moment calculate the Price, and next time I call it to calculate Tax? My hope is to do this without using If-statements but I'm not sure if this is possible.

Appreciate any help.

EDIT: Spelling

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an existing [`Sum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Sum__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Double__) method from [System.Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq?view=netframework-4.8) namespace without writing it by yourself

```cs
double price = temp.Sum(item => item.Price);
double tax = temp.Sum(item => item.Tax);
```

Comment: Thank you! I will use this method!

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the Aggregate LINQ extension method like below.

```
var totalPrice = temp.Aggregate((p1, p2) => p1.Price + p2.Price);
var totalTax = temp.Aggregate((t1, t2) => t1.Tax + t2.Tax);
```